# How to reference a dynamically created text box

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript or jquery, how would I reference some text boxes which were dynamically created.
I have the following javascript which references one text box, but when the other text boxes are created, they have different id's. Any ideas's?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#lst_vat').change(function(){

  var inpvat = $('#lst_vat').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:({id : inpvat}),
            dataType:'json',
        url:"phpcode/get_vat_rate.php",
        //url:"ajax_product_list.php",
        success: function(data){
            $('.results').html(data);
             $('#txt_line_vat').val(data.vat_rate_value);    
            }
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any control over how the textboxes are generated? Typically you could just add some pre-defined class on their creation that would allow you to get at them later.

Comment: Do you want the same function to be bound to the change event on all the generated text boxes?

Comment: Yes Patrick, I would, Ihave a form with a list box "#lst_vat" and when I select an option from it, I can populate a number of text boxes with the data contained in a row, returned by the json script, my challenge though is if Idynamically creat an other row in the form and select an option from the new list box, I am unable to update the newly created text fields.

Comment: Hi, can anyone help me with this as I am struggling a bit,:)

Comment: I think you need to use [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) Read the section on delegated events.

Comment: How the ids of the textboxes look like? Are you able/allowed to modify the code which generates them?

Comment: Hi, I am using relcopy to dynamically create new rows in my form.Iam post the form as an array. At the moment, the id's are the field names with out the [] for the array. When I run the page through firebug, I can see that the id names are being appended with 1, i.e. txt_description in the first row has an id of description, in the first dynamically created row, it has an id of description1 and so on description2 for the second row  etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using either class attribute or name attribute of textarea and ofcourse Javascript.